# Laravel: Understanding which api framework to choose

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

Our company is about to start a real estate project and have decided to go with the laravel 5.3 framework. The first phase is to write the apis and then these apis will be consumed by the mobile team and the frontend team to build the official mobile app and the web portal respectively.

Now I am confused whether to use laravel's built-in Resource controllers (as instructed in this tutorial http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-build-restful-apis-using-php-and-laravel/how-to/2014/08/13) or use the Dingo Api framework.

Could you please help me which one should I go for and why as per the requirements i mentioned above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Play with both approaches first and decide.

Comment: why to separate the logic?

Comment: @TheAlpha Does the resource controller support JWT authentication?

Comment: I do not see an added value for the Dingo Api. With the updated Laravel 5.3, you have many great API functionality built in.

Comment: @Phantom007, Yes with Laravel 5.3, you can use Passport for JWT.

Comment: Yes! You would do the auth using middleware.

Comment: @MinaAbadir I dont see an official documentation on laravel website regarding the resource controller api, can u help me find it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Because it's part of the Main functionalities, read about Routing and Controllers, and you will find all the required information.

Comment: Right @TheAlpha JWT support isnt mentioned anywhere. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: from laravel 5.3 there's a separate route file for api. and the framework started to push in this direction in a very good attitude

Comment: @MinaAbadir Do you think with laravel 5.3 we would need a third party library like fractal?

Comment: @Phantom007 that's totally up top you, if you can build your data arrays, and post it to your API then no need for Fractal. otherwise, it's up to you.

Comment: @MinaAbadir So you mean to say that Fractal does not help with speeding up the performance for heavy data?

Answer (score 1):

Since, Laravel 5.3 comes with Passport (for api authentication), I would suggest you to use Resource controller, which is very simple and easy to work with, and also it create a meaningful end points

```
Route::resource('post','PostController');

GET /post/{post}
POST /post
EDIT /post/{post}/edit
DELETE /post/{post}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I want JWT based authentication can I do it with laravel 5.3 alone?

Comment: Passport comes with oauth2.0 and which supports jwt also.

Comment: Is there any specific link where i can learn how to implement jwt using passport?

Comment: https://jagadeshanh.wordpress.com/2016/12/27/using-laravel-passport-for-api-authentication/ hope this helps you

Comment: Great! Thanks for writing an article on it. Few questions however 

(1) To get the JWT, you made a POST request with client_id and client_secret. So how will my customers know this id and secret? Will these be fixed for ALL my customers?

(2) If I want to have diff client_id and client_secret for each customer, do I have to manually run php artisan passport:install everytime?

Thanks

Comment: It completely depends on you, If you want to implement something like facebook apps, then each user who creates an app will get client_id, or you just have one android app, and one web app, then just create two clients one for android and one for web and use these credentials. check this link for more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Comment: I just want my users to be able to get a json token when they pass their username and password and nothing else. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check Requesting tokens in that passport documentation. There is an example also.

Comment: All the examples require you to specify the client_id :(

Comment: @Phantom007 yes bro, with one client_id, you can have many Bearer tokens, I will post an example wait.

Comment: But its not the right way, I cannot tell all my third party api users to use the same client id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131616/discussion-between-jagadesha-nh-and-phantom007).